# In Javascript, can a local function be invoked dynamically knowing its name string?

Tags: javascript

Global functions can be accessed by their names as in:

```
        x = function () {
            alert(1);
        }
        window['x']();
```

This will execute the function. But when I have something like this:

```
        function outer() {
           var inner = function() {

                   }
           window['inner'](); //This will not execute as inner is not global.
        }
```

Is there any way to get around this? Application: I am trying to avoid using a switch statement where the action for each case is merely to execute a specific function based upon the value of the string. Having these functions named based upon the potential string value, entire switch statements are reduced to one statement. Example:

```
           switch (someString) {
             case 'value1' : myValue1Func();
                             break;
             case 'value2' : myValue2Func();
                             break;
              ...
            }
```

Can be condensed into one:

```
         window ["my" + someString + "Func"]();
```

But this will only work for global functions. I do not want to make local functions global just to do this.

Comment: The answer is no. In your case, `inner` is declared without `let` or `var` so it actually *would* be global. Generally any situation that leads a person to ask a question like this is an indication of some upstream design mistake.

Comment: @Pointy that missing var or let was a typo.  I corrected it.

Comment: `{ value1: myValue1Func, ... }[someString]()`

Comment: @JonasWilms  You are still maintaining a mapping which is effectively a simplified switch statement anyway albeit a better approach than the switch.

Comment: @Sunny how is `var inner = function() {} window['inner']();` any different to a map? You still need to create the functions and name them accordingly. If "maintaining a mapping" is the actual issue, then I'm afraid you wont get around it.

Comment: @Olian04 You and Jonas are right. I cannot get around this issue other than making the functions global or maintaining a "mapping" in some form.  If the functions are global, the mapping is not required.

Comment: @Sunny making them global and accessing them through the window object, is the exact same thing as what Jones suggested, it's just using slightly different syntax.

Comment: @Olian04 OK. I get it. Thanks